# Python 2.7- Subtracting two decimals (4.3 and 2.7) but not getting a specific answer

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I subtract 4.7 from 2.3, I get a number with 16 decimal places, instead of getting a specific number with one decimal place. How come it doesn't give you a specific answer?

Comment: Additionally, please note that you should always use the generic [python] tag and include any version specific tags, optionally.

Comment: If you really need a precise value, Python has the `decimal` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the numerical representation of both decimal numbers (`4.7` and `2.3`) in binary:

> 4.7 is represented in binary as 100.10110011001100110011...
>
> 2.3 is represented in binary as 10.01001100110011001101...

As you can see, both are periodic tithes in binary. This is why you do not obtain a precise result.

I hope it helps.